# Rename "Shipping address to "Delivery address" in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, gettext

client wants to rename "Shipping Address" to "Delivery Address" It is only visible in two places, one the "Ship to different address" title that appears on checkout page and two on the customer confirmation email.

Have tried text replace functions but no joy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Shipping address" text is visible on multiple locations:

- Order received page (after checkout)
- My account > Order view
- My account > Adresses
- My account > Adresses > Edit shipping address
- Email notifications

The best and easy way is to use the following hooked function:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'rename_shipping_address_text', 10, 3 );
function rename_shipping_address_text( $translated, $text, $domain ) {

    if ( $text === 'Shipping address' ) {
        $translated = __('Delivery address', $domain );
    }

    return $translated;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

Please copy this two Files from the Wooommerce Plugin and put it in your Active theme's folder like this.

```
Active Theme
    Woocommerce(If now available please create this folder)
        emails
            email-addresses.php
        checkout
            form-shipping.php
```

In this two files, you have to change.